# How to re save (copy) audio file in document directory and send that re saved audio file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, audio-recording

I'm working on record audio file and send to server. Record, stop, play and sending working properly. But my problem is if i click stop button i want to re save that audio file with new name in docs dir and send this audio file to server. My code is...

```
// File path where the recording will be saved on the iOS device
audioFilePath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory].path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"RecordAudio.wav"];
NSLog(@"%@", audioFilePath);

NSURL *outputFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioFilePath];

// Setup audio session
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:nil];

// Define the recorder setting
NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool: NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool: NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityHigh] forKey:AVEncoderAudioQualityKey];

// Initiate and prepare the recorder
NSError *error = nil;
audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:outputFileURL settings:recordSetting error:&error];
audioRecorder.delegate = self;
audioRecorder.meteringEnabled = YES;

// Deal with any errors
if (error)
NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
else
[audioRecorder prepareToRecord];

// Check to see if we have permission to use the microphone.
if ([session respondsToSelector:@selector(requestRecordPermission:)]) {
    [session performSelector:@selector(requestRecordPermission:) withObject:^(BOOL granted) {
        if (granted) {
            NSLog(@"Mic access granted");
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Mic access NOT granted");
        }
    }];
}

-(NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {

NSLog(@"%@", [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
                                                     inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]);
return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
                                               inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}

- (IBAction)record:(id)sender {

NSLog(@"Started Recording");
if (!audioRecorder.recording)
{
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:nil];
    [session setActive:YES error:nil];

    // Start recording
    [audioRecorder record];
}
}

- (IBAction)stop:(id)sender {

NSLog(@"Stop Recording");
if ([audioRecorder isRecording])
{
    [audioRecorder stop];
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    [audioSession setActive:NO error:nil];

}
else if (audioPlayer.playing)
[audioPlayer stop];
}
```

If i write this code in stop method ..

```
NSLog(@"%@", audioRecorder.url); // RecordAudio.wav
NSString *urlString = [audioRecorder.url.absoluteString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"RecordAudio.wav" withString:@"RecordAudio2.wav"];
self.sendingURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSLog(@"%@", self.sendingURL);
```

When i click stop button i'm getting error
    Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 2003334207.)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the name of that audio file. What you can do is create a copy of that audio file with your new name using the NSFileManager class

```
 NSFileManager *fManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    [fManager copyItemAtURL:oldURL toURL:newURL error:error];
```

Comment: Fine, thank u. I did like this..  NSLog(@"%@", audioRecorder.url); // RecordAudio.wav.         NSString *urlString = [audioRecorder.url.absoluteString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"RecordAudio.wav" withString:@".RecordAudio5.wav"];
self.sendingURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];   NSLog(@"%@", self.sendingURL);       Now i am sending with new name called "RecordAudio5.wav" it's working. Fine thank u for your reply...